# Server-client password / username check in Java

Tags: java, passwords, client-server

I'm building a simple client-server architecture where a client connects to a server and then the server asks for the client's username and password. The usernames and passwords should be kept in a text file. If they are correct, the client should be allowed to enter commands for the server.

What might be the best way to go about this, including the formatting of the text file where the items should be drawn from?

Thanks.

Comment: When a client enters password on registration, compute hash of password and store hash value in textfile along with the username. If the client signs in again, compute the hash of the password and compare. Never store passwords in the clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BufferedReader or Scanner to read the username and password from the file. To edit the file, you can use BufferedWriter.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\the\\path\\of_file.txt")));
String password = br.readLine();
```

To edit it, you can use:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\file.path")));
bw.write(new_password);
bw.close();
```

All the Classes are available in the package **java.io**

Answer (score 0):

> What might be the best way to go about this

If security is an issue, you should first examine how to safely store password. [crackingstation.net](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) might be you first stop on that topic.

> including the formatting of the text file where the items should be drawn from

This is only a very rough model to keep it as simple as possible:

- Create a class `LoginManager` which manages the login information
- Make that class serializable by implementing the corresponding interface
- On server start up, deserialize the stored information
- At runtime, manipulate the collection of login credentials e.g.

  - add new login data (account creation)
  - edit existing data (change password request)
  - delete data (user wants to delete his account)
- On server shut down, serialize the data.

Here a **very basic** idea for the class:

```
public class LoginManager implements Serializable {
    /** storage for login credentials */
    private final Map<String, String> loginData = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    public boolean addUser(final String username, final String password) {
        if (loginData.containsKey(username)) {
            return false;
        }

        loginData.put(username, password);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean existUser(final String username) {
        return loginData.containsKey(username);
    }

    public boolean checkPassword(final String username, final String password) {
        return loginData.get(username).equals(password);
    }
}
```